# PHP - Url in CURLOPT_URL is not found

Tags: php

I want to call the script in upload.php with `curl_exec` from the script `init.php`. This script is located in the same folder than `upload.php`.

I am trying to put the url as following:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/upload.php');`

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, './upload.php');`

But it doesn't work. Is there any way to use a variable path 'root' or something like this?

Comment: `./upload.php` --- this is not a valid URL (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3). Why do you want to curl a script that is available locally?

Comment: I want to pass a json object as parameter to this local php script. Which alternative do I have?

Comment: Nobody knows - your question lacks details about what `upload.php` consists of, how else it is used and what your current task is.

Comment: The `A.php` file has a variable string with value "hello world" and I want to pass this variable to `B.php`. `B.php` should get this variable and print it with the value "hello world". Both pages are located in the same folder. Can PHP do this?

Comment: I guess with `include`

Comment: The normal way to do this kind of this is with `include`. `B.php` should define a function that `A.php` can call, passing the string as an argument.